# Trouble reading char by char from a file in C++

Tags: c++, string, file-io, stringstream

So I have this piece of code:

```
ifstream sFile;
sFile.open(argv[1]);
stringstream ss;
unsigned char aChar;
string aString;

while (sFile >> noskipws >> aChar) {
    ss << noskipws << aChar;
}
ss >> noskipws >> aString;
cout << noskipws << aString << endl;
```

My file contains:
"SHE SMELLS"

In stdout, all I see is "SHE". I've wasted so much time trying to figure this out, can someone help me understand why this is happening?

Also, will this be able to read in characters from the extended ascii alphabet?

Comment: Using `getline (ss, aString);` instead of `ss >> aString` should work, but I've never actually tried `getline` with `stringstream`.

Comment: This seems to work now. Do you by any chance know if the above code ignores any characters? I need to be able to deal with an extended ascii alphabet.

Comment: You might want UTF8 or UTF16 strings then, depending what you need to store.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this page for noskipws:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/manipulators/noskipws/

In the example it shows the problem you are having, it is fixed by using:

```
iss.seekg(0);
```

This should work if you do this:

```
sFile.seekg(0);
```

before your while loop.
Hope that is right / helps.